# Django не видит русские буквы

Tags: python, django

В модели Django переопределяю метод save(), для того чтобы slug формировался автоматически. С английскими буквами всё работает нормально и slug формируется корректно, но с русскими буквами в бд ничего не сохраняется.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.slug:
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Думаю что руские символы оставлять в бд будет не очень хорошо. Можно перед этим [транслитерировать](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F) текст и уже с ним работать потом.

Можно использовать модуль [transliterate](https://pypi.org/project/transliterate/) для этого.

```
from transliterate import translit
# pip install transliterate

def my_slugify(text):
    return slugify(translit(text, 'ru', reversed=True))
```